# JPQL - Select cars rented by more than 10 different customers

Tags: mysql, spring, jpql

I have 3 Entities: **Car**, **Rental** and **Customer**. 
Rental is related with Car and Customer.

I need to write query finding cars rented by more than 10 different customers

Following code:

```
@Override
    public List<CarEntity> findCarsRentedByDifferentCustomers() {

        TypedQuery<CarEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT car FROM CarEntity car join car.rentals cr " +
                "WHERE(SELECT COUNT(re) FROM RentalEntity re " +
                "join re.customer c " +
                "GROUP BY c.id) > 10", CarEntity.class
        );

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

I always get `DataIntegrityViolationException` or `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`. I'd already tried to write this query in many different ways.

Comment: I think the real issue here is your query, not JPQL so much.  It would help to see some table/entity structure here along with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can be more like the query below. 
The inner query matches car_id's from the Rental table and checks if more then  10 unique customers has rented a unique car.

Please note you may need to change the query into using the correct table columns you are using. 
You didn't provide a table structure and example data.

```
SELECT 
 Car.*
FROM
 Car
WHERE
 Car.id IN (

  SELECT 
   Rental.car_id
  FROM 
   Rental 
  GROUP BY 
   Rental.car_id
  HAVING 
   COUNT(DISTINCT Rental.customer_id) > 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, the query would look like:

```
SELECT cr.car
FROM car.rentals cr 
GROPU BY cr.car
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT re.customer) >= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

use.agregate function sql code is below

```
   select c.id  from car c inner join
    rentals r on      c.rentalid=r.rentalid
    group by c.id 
    having count（distinct customerid）>10
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake was that I tried to group by customer.id not car.id  and I was trying to find a bug in jpql query syntax.
Now my code looks like:

```
@Override
    public List<CarEntity> findCarsRentedByDifferentCustomers() {

        TypedQuery<CarEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select car from CarEntity car " +
                "where car.id in (select re.car.id from RentalEntity re " +
                "group by re.car.id " +
                "having count(distinct re.customer.id) > 10)", CarEntity.class
        );

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

@Raymond Nijland, @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin thank you for answers